# error while sniffing HTTPS with fiddler

Tags: https, router, fiddler, sniffing

it shows this error

```
    fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to 192.168.1.1 (for #2) failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. < The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

`HTTPS handshake returned error SEC_E_ALGORITHM_MISMATCH
Fiddler's Enabled HTTPS Protocols: [Default] are controlled inside Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH89N.png)

Comment: please write your question clearly. Consult this page before doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: bro what is  not clear with the question ?

Comment: correct it for me please i don't know what is wrong !!